# Como corrigir no meu código: Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, jsf-2.2

minha base de dados tem os responsáveis com valores de "Supervisor" e "Gerente". Porém, faço uma busca para pegar os Empregados responsaveis e retorno nulo. Vejam meu método getResponsaveis em minha classe "**EmpregadoDAO.java**":

```
public List<Empregado> getResponsaveis() {
    Funcao funcao = new Funcao();

    TypedQuery tq = this.em.createQuery(
        "select e from Empregado e INNER JOIN Funcao f ON e.funcao.id = f.",
        Empregado.class
    );

    String[] responsaveis = {"Supervisor", "Gerente"};        
    tq.setParameter("supervisor", responsaveis[0]);
    tq.setParameter("gerente", responsaveis[1]);

    try {
        return tq.getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Estou puxando essas informações em minha classe **AlmoxarifadoController.java** para pegar esses responsáveis em um campo select em minha view:

```
public List<Empregado> getResponsaveis() {
        return this.empregadoDAO.getResponsaveis();
}
```

Em minha view, esta da seguinte forma:

```
<h:outputLabel for="responsavel" value="Reponsável" rendered="false"/>
<h:selectOneMenu id="funcao" value="#{almoxarifadoController.empregadoAlmoxarifado}" class="form-control custom-select">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione um responsável" itemValue="#{null}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{almoxarifadoController.responsaveis}" var="responsavel" itemLabel="#{responsavel.nome}" itemValue="#{responsavel.id}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

A Mensagem de erro no meu console é:

```
Advertência:   StandardWrapperValve[FacesServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet FacesServlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.com.loogix.controller.AlmoxarifadoController.getResponsaveis(AlmoxarifadoController.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UISelectItems.getValue(UISelectItems.java:129)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.SelectItemsIterator.initializeItems(SelectItemsIterator.java:208)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.SelectItemsIterator.hasNext(SelectItemsIterator.java:135)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderOptions(MenuRenderer.java:762)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderSelect(MenuRenderer.java:847)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(MenuRenderer.java:297)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Qual é o valor da variável `empregadoDAO`?

Comment: Pelo o erro parece que a variável empregadoDAO não foi inicializada.